# qapitrace.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: qt, opengl

I have the following problem when I try to run qapitrace with apitrace file that was created:[image: qapitrace.exe - Entry Point Not Found]

For analyzing trace I use the following command:

```
qapitrace Coin.trace
```

Also, the system variable PATH include the path to QT libraries

For creating the trace file I the use following command:

```
apitrace trace --api gl Coin.exe
```

For build APITrace I use the following software:

1. Windows 7 x 64
2. Cmake - 3.8.2
3. QT - 5.11.2
4. Visual Studio 2017

For compile the following commands was used:

```
1. cmake -H. -Bbuild -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\5.11.2\msvc2015
2. cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo
```

Comment: This is probably libraries incompatibility issue. Probably your Qt built with another compiler than VS2017.

Comment: QT I download and install it without direct compiling. About APITrace I use the following instruction: https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.markdown
and the following instruction has the following:
Note as off Qt version 5.9.1 there's no `msvc2017` directory, only `msvc2015`
and `msvc2017_64`, but `msvc2015` should work as MSVC 2017 is binary backwards
compatible with MSVC 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the following libraries were not copied:

1. Qt5Widgets.dll
2. Qt5Gui.dll
3. Qt5Core.dll

And Instead of these libraries was copied the following:

1. Qt5Widgetsd.dll
2. Qt5Guid.dll
3. Qt5Cored.dll

I compile it for RelWithDebInfo and Release, after adding the libraries everything works fine.